# Charged particle following magnetic field lines

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

For a charged particle in a magnetic field the equation of motion is
$$\frac {d \vec v}{dt}=\frac q m \left[\frac {\vec v} c \times \vec B(\vec x)\right]$$

Then, if $\vec B$ is a slowly changing field the motion $\vec v(t)=v_0 \frac {\vec B(\vec x)}{B(\vec x)}$, that represent a particle following the magnetic field line, is a good approximated solution of the problem (I know it represents a particular case but it's the one I'm interested in).

**Even if I understand that this is a good approximation, I don't know which method should be used in order to derive this approximated solution from the original problem**

I tired zero order Taylor expansion, but the result is different, indeed expanding the field around $\vec x_0$ and considering the zero order term:
$$\vec B(\vec x)=\vec B(\vec x_0)$$
So the equation of motion becomes
$$\frac {d \vec v}{dt}=\frac q m \left[\frac {\vec v} c \times \vec B(\vec x_0)\right]$$

A solution of this equation is $\vec v=v_0 \frac {\vec B(\vec x_0)}{B(\vec x_0)}$, namely the particle follow a straight line.

Maybe I should use also the first order term but the equations doesn't look  promising.

Comment: It's surprising that there is no discussion of the initial velocity in your question, especially when dealing with the magnetic field.

Comment: there isn't because i'm not interesting in the cyclotrone motion. I'm interested in that specific approximated solution (if you like, it corresponds to an initial velocity parallel to the magnetic field line)

Comment: It seems you've already derived the solution based on the $0$th term of the Taylor expansion. If the particle's velocity is parallel to the direction of a slowly varying magnetic field (i.e., constant magnetic field based on the $0$th order approximation), what else would you expect?

Comment: the $0$th order approximation gives a straight line as trajectory, while the approximated solution i'm looking for is the particle following the field line (that is weakly curved)

Comment: The only situations I've seen where charges (approximately) follow field lines involve a high-frequency cyclotron motion around the field line, and then a "slow" (adiabatic) change in the magnetic field direction and intensity along the field line.  Are you sure that a particle with no cyclotron motion will still follow the field lines?

Comment: If the field line is weakly curved $\vec v=v_0 \vec b(\vec x)$, where $\vec b$ is the vector tangent to the field line, should be a good approximation. Indeed, the right term of the equation is zero, while the left term is $\frac {\partial \vec v}{\partial t}=v_0 \frac {\partial\vec b}{\partial\vec x} \frac {\partial \vec x}{\partial t}$ and $\frac {\partial\vec b}{\partial\vec x}$ is small by assumption.

Comment: Yes, but compared to what are you calling $\vec{\nabla} \vec{B}$ "small"?  In the more common adiabatic approximation I'm familiar with, you have $|\vec{\nabla} \vec{B}| \ll |\vec{B}| \omega_c/v$, where $\omega_c$ is the cyclotron frequency and $v$ is the particle's speed.  But it seems like you're comparing it to a term that is exactly zero, and it's not negligible compared to zero.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at Aguirre, Luque, & Peralta-Salas, ["Motion of charged particles in magnetic fields created by symmetric configurations of wires"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167278910000412), Physica D **239**, 654–674 (2010).  The authors look at the trajectories of charged particles in the vicinity of a long infinite wire and of a circular loop.  To my eye, it does not look like the trajectories are well-approximated by the field lines except perhaps in the "adiabatic" case I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

"i don't know which method should be used in order to derive this approximated solution from the original problem"

Surely all that is needed is to recognise that when the $\vec v$ is in the same direction as $\vec B$ there is no magnetic force on the particle (right hand side of equation zero), so there is no resultant acceleration (left hand side zero).

[This doesn't mean, though, that the particle will follow the magnetic field line; if the particle maintains its velocity (magnitude and direction) and travels into a region where the field direction changes, the magnetic Lorentz force, $q\vec v \times \vec B$, will take it even further from the field line!]

What other sort of explanation are you looking for?

Comment: If the magnetic field line is weakly curved $\vec v$ parallel to $\vec B$ is just an approximated solution, indeed the velocity would change direction and so its derivative is not zero. What i'm searching for is a method to derive the approximated solution from the equation of motion